# Home and Search icon not showing in Jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

The Home and search icons not displaying during the output and its just showing as an hyperlink  Plz help Here is my coding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left">Search</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be a CSS issue. Post your CSS data...

Comment: Instead of downloading the jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css CSS file,jquery-1.11.1.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js from Http://jquerymobile.com/download/ website,I tried to copy paste the links 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

and it works,dont know why it does not work when I download

Comment: As you say the <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"> does not work and When I use the link 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"> it works

Comment: of course they won't be displayed. You should use 1.4.3 style sheet. jQM 1.3 uses png icons, 1.4 uses SVG icons.

Comment: downloaded the 1.4.3 version and it worked,Thanks all for your quick responses and this issue is solved within minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just downloaded the 1.4.3 version and added it and it worked

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css">
```